C++ struct initialization using own type
Using custom constructor, a struct can be initialized using own type.
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
    Foo(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
    Foo(const Foo& f) : Foo(f.x, f.y) {}
};
Foo foo1(1, 2);
Foo foo2 = Foo(foo1);

However, I found that declaring the constructor wasn't necessary.
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
    Foo(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
    // Foo(const Foo& f) : Foo(f.x, f.y) {} <-- This can be omitted.
};
Foo foo1(1, 2);
Foo foo2 = Foo(foo1);

I wonder how is this possible.

Side note: Foo foo2 = Foo(foo1); can be written more concisely as Foo foo2(foo1);.

Another side note : Foo(const Foo&) is called a copy consturctor (not initialization using your own type). Also read up on the rule of 3/5/0. When you declare a constructor the default constructor is implicitly deleted. And when you have a copy constructor you also should implement operator=(const Foo&)

Oh and you could just have left out declaring your own copy constructor, since the members can be trivially copied the implicit default copy constructor would have done the job (rule of 0)

Special member functions - Some member functions are special: under certain circumstances they are defined by the compiler even if not defined by the user. They are:
Default constructor,
Copy constructor,
Move constructor (since C++11),
Copy assignment operator,
Move assignment operator (since C++11),
Destructor

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor:

If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type, the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class. This implicitly-declared copy constructor has the form T::T(const T&)...

